# How to convert List<Object> into comma separated String

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I am getting list of `Address` objects from the DB call.

```
ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Each `Address` has an `int addressId` property.

I am writing an update query where in the `IN` clause I am sending this whole list of `Address` objects and I am getting ibatis `TypeException`. How can I convert `List<Address>` to a comma separated string which can be sent to update query?

My update query looks like:::

```
Update tablename set postcode = #{postCode} where id in #{addressID}.
```

Comment: Consider this approach again. In particular, read about SQL injection.

Comment: @Henry Converting into string and sending in IN clause will not solve the problem?I dont know how to pass list in update query..

Comment: It will solve this problem but create a new one (a security vulnerability).

Comment: @Henry Creating a new one means.Sorry i did not understood..

Comment: I don't see how SQL injection is possible in this case. There is no user input that can affect the creation of the `addressID` string in any way, and `addressId` field has an integer type.

Answer (score 61):

Using Java 8 you could do it in one line:

```
String addressID = addresses
           .stream()
           .map(a -> String.valueOf(a.addressId))
           .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: a non "List<string>" example!! Thank you !

Comment: and if `addresses` is null?

Answer (score 16):

for converting to comma seperated String use something like this:

```
String commaSeparatedStr = addresses
        .stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: In case someone need a comma separated of variable inside Address object, use the getter inside map `.map(c -> String.valueOf(c.getName()))`

Answer (score 8):

[`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-), which accepts delimiter `String` and `Iterable` elements (which is `List` in your case)

```
 List<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
 strings.add("Java");
 strings.add("is");
 strings.add("cool");
 String message = String.join(",", strings); //pass delimiter and List
 //message returned is: "Java,is,cool"
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the address objects, retrieve their ID and create a String. Something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (Address a: adresses) {
  sb.append(a.getId());
  sb.append(", ");
}

String ids = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String.join(", ", addresses) ;
```

Comment: Super simple. Super good.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder addressIds = new StringBuilder("");
for(Address address : addresses){
  if (addressIds.length() > 1)  
    addressIds.append(", ");
  addressIds.append("'").append(address.id()).append("'");
}

//in this method you can directly send the string in Update tablename + set postcode + where id in <String>.
methodOfUpdateInQuery(addressIds.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The format required can be obtained using `toString()` and `replaceAll()` methods (using regular Expressions).

```java
String addressString = addresses.toString().replaceAll("[ \\[ \\] ]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

List of `int` - let Java do it:

```
String tmp = addresses.toString();
String csList = tmp.substring(1, tmp.length()-1);
```